# Non consant size alphabet

Tags: algorithms, strings

Sometimes I read that an algorithm works on constant size alphabet and it is clear for me but what means that an algorithm works with a non constant size alphabet? I would like to see an example.

Comment: The question seems to be missing some context. Can you give an example where you saw that an algorithm worked on a constant size alphabet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classical example is *sorting*. For any constant-size alphabet, you can sort a string of length $n$ in time $O(n)$. However, for unbounded alphabets, the best you can do (under the comparison model, as well as some of its generalizations) is $\Theta(n\log n)$.

Comment: For unbounded you mean infinity, i. e. the alphabet is not a set of finite letters but for example the set of all natural numbers, right?

Comment: You can probably prove linearithmic lower bounds in some models even for finite alphabets whose sizes grow with $n$.

Comment: What means finite alphabets whose sizes grow with n? Sorry but I am misunderstanding something. Size and cardinality of a set are the same? Can you give an example with non constant size alphabet? Usaually I think an alphabet with fine elemnts such as A,C,T,G, alphabet of DNA. Thanks

Comment: Size and cardinality are the same thing. The numbers 1 to $n$ form an alphabet of size $n$.

Comment: Can you give an example of problem with non constant size alphabet?

Comment: Sorting is such an example.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answers.